# Addressing Backends

Tags: google-app-engine, backend

Google says at [Addressing Backends chapter](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Addressing_Backends) that without targeting an instance by number, App Engine selects the first available instance of the backend. That makes me wondering – what is that “first available instance”? Is it the instance #1, or is it picked by some other methods?

Comment: What difference does it make? "available" is an instance that is not currently serving a request/running your code. They're all equivalent (within a single backend config)

Comment: It makes some difference, see the excellent answer below. I just needed to be sure what is the way of selecting that “available” instance, as I would need to write a load-balancing code on my own if it behaved in another way.

Comment: Mine was a rhetorical question.

Comment: Didn’t seem like that to me. My point was that “available” in the documentation is not very descriptive about the whole addressing process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact behavior of this depends on if your instances are dynamic or resident.

For dynamic instances, the request goes to the first instance that can handle the request immediately. If there are no instances that can handle the request immediately, the request is queued or a new instance is started, depending on queueing settings.

For resident instances, the request is sent to the least-loaded backend instance.

The reason for the different behaviors is to make the best use of your instances: resident instances are there anyway, so they're utilized equally, while dynamic instances are spawned only as needed, so the scheduler tries to avoid spinning up new ones if it can.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know. So, I don’t need to write any kind of load-balancing code on my own (for dynamic private backends), which would anyway not be 100 % reliable or easy to implement. I will have to look for the queueing settings though, I don’t remember seeing it anywhere.